Errors in `NIntegrate` - or in coding?
As far as I know, if a set of functions f,g,h,... are all Riemann integrable then the definite integral of the sum f+g+h over the interval [1,x] should be equal to the sum of the separate integrals over [1,x] of f and g and h.
In my case, the integrals must be calculated using NIntegrate because Mathematica won't play nicely with the Floor function element in the functions.
But for whatever reason, the integral of the sum does not match the sum of the integrals:
f[x_] := Sum[Floor[u]*((k*u*Cos[Pi*(u + k*u - x)])/(u + k*u - x)), 
   {k, 1, Floor[x] - 1}]; 
g[x_] := Sum[Floor[u]*((k^2*u*Cos[Pi*(u + k*u - x)])/(u + k*u - x)), 
   {k, 1, Floor[x] - 1}]; 
h[x_] := Sum[Floor[u]*((k^2*u*Cos[k*Pi*u - Pi*x])/(k*u - x)), 
   {k, 1, Floor[x] - 1}]; 

Table[{x, NIntegrate[f[x] + g[x] - h[x], {u, 1, x}], 
  NIntegrate[f[x], {u, 1, x}] + NIntegrate[g[x], {u, 1, x}] - 
    NIntegrate[h[x], {u, 1, x}]}, {x, 2, 5, 1/2}]


{{2, 300.5118851, 442.9860989}, {5/2, 736.7297006, 743.1447953}, {3,
894.7316167, 904.577171}, {7/2, 1550.215739, 1571.798798}, {4, 1770.592955,
2035.875269}, {9/2, 2678.596999, 2687.159346}, {5, 2984.444006,
3038.680717}}

Is this just a result of using NIntegrate? If It's numerical error, is there a work-around to obtain more accurate results?
Or am I doing something completely wrong, either in my coding or in my maths?

I don't know about you, but NIntegrate gives me a bunch of "failed to converge" errors. It makes me think that is where to look for the problem.

You integrate over "u" but you function are given as "f[x]".

Thanks @Daniel. Just FYI, the x vs u thing is deliberate; this is part of a bigger function with many variables, and the required result is its value for a given x.

I agree about the errors, @Michael. They make me suspicious too. But I am at a loss for alternatives, because plain old Integrate just won't work with Floor...

Your math is wrong, the functions have singularities and are not integrable, at least in the case x=2, which I checked.

Hi @yarchick. OK, thank you. There are certainly discontinuities at integer x because of the floor function... But since each interval [1,2], [2,3], [3,4] etc are separately integrable, my understanding was that the functions still counted as Riemann integrable over the entire [1,x] interval. Perhaps I am wrong, or perhaps there is some other issue? Is it something I could get around by using PrincipalValue, for example?

I am voting to close this question because it is just a simple mistake. There is nothing to fix here with PrincipalValue, just set x=2, and plot the functions in the integration interval.

I think @yarchik means, for example that FunctionSingularities[f[3], u] shows a pole at u == 3/2, which is within the interval of integration. The principal value is an approach, if valid.

I take that back about principal value. The Floor[u] means some PVs do not exist in your problem.

@MichaelE2 The whole approach does not work if it does not work in some cases. It is sufficient to Plot[f[2] + g[2] - h[2], {u, 1, 2}] to see two non-integrable singularities at x=1 and at x=2. Maybe there are also integrable singularities in other cases. But what is the point of such in depth analysis when already the simplest case diverges?

@MichaelE2 Probably I misunderstood your comment, I thought you seek a way to fix the f[3] case.

@yarchik No, I was agreeing with you. I suggested PV just looking at the denominators, and took it back in my 2nd comment after realizing the effect of floor[] on the asymptotes at integers. As you said, there's no point going into it much.

Thanks to you all

NIntegrate approximates integrals by interpolation of the functions via Legendre or other polynomial smooth series by a series of refining intervals until the primitive numerical evaluation of integrated polynomials  becomes stationary.
This process does not produce reliable approximations for functions with discontinuities in any order of derivatives, that is becoming visible at a certain resolution.
Generally, Riemann integrals have to be subdivided into sums of integrals over intervalls of smoothness of derivatives up to the order of the number of evaluation points.
